# Creating a private dns zone a record in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

So I have a terraform script where I am creating a private DNS zone (`azurerm_private_dns_zone.flexpsql`) with a network link. I need to create an A record in a separate private DNS zone (`data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.main`) that is connected to my organizations network. How do I automatically get the IP address from the A record that is generated by the private DNS I just created?

This would be my terraform:

```
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "flexpsql" {
  name                = "${local.flexpsql_name}.private.postgres.database.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = var.vnet_resource_group_name

}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "flexpsql" {
  name                  = local.flexpsql_name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.flexpsql.name
  virtual_network_id    = var.virtual_network_id
  resource_group_name   = var.vnet_resource_group_name
}
```

I then will need to create an Private DNS A Record in another existing Private DNS

```
resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "example" {
  name                = "${local.flexpsql_name}"
  zone_name           = data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.other.name
  resource_group_name = "rgtest111"
  ttl                 = 3600
  records             = split(",", join(",", azurerm_private_dns_a_record.flexpsql.records))
}
```

I will test the above.. But ultimately this is what I want to achieve

Comment: Can you share your complete terraform code?

Comment: What actually `azurerm_private_dns_zone.flexpsql` is in your code?

Comment: Ok my apologies for lacking more information. I will edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to create a private DNS zone record using the network link created for another DNS zone and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

To automatically retrieve the IP address from the record generated by the private DNS zone you just created, you can use the data block in Terraform. The data block allows you to fetch information from existing resources or data sources.

In the first step, I created a **`private_dns_zone.main`** with a network link.

My terraform configuration:

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example"{
    name = "v-bolliv"
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "main" {
  name                = "mydomainvk.com"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "main" {
  name                = "testvk"
  zone_name           = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  ttl                 = 3600
  records             = ["10.0.180.17"]
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now inorder to use this network link `azurerm_private_dns_zone.main`  for the new `azurerm_private_dns_zone.example`

**My terraform configuration:**

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "main"{
    name = "v-bolliv"
}

data "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "main" {
  name                = "mydomainvk.com"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}


data "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "main"{
  name                = "testvk"
  zone_name           = data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.main.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}


resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "mydomainvksb.com"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "example" {
  name                = "testsbvk"
  zone_name           = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  ttl                 = 3600
  records             = split(",", join(",", data.azurerm_private_dns_a_record.main.records))
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now as per requirement check the network IP provided
by checking the output module.

**Output module:**

```
output  "private_dns_records" {

value  =  [azurerm_private_dns_a_record.example.records]

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this response. The only difference between my code and yours is that my azurerm_private_dns_zone.main generates the a record automatically, so I won't know the name of the a record. I will need to play around  with this and get back to you